# Rewrite API -Adding a parameter before the slug

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm looking into how to optionally prefix the permalink structure. And passing the prefix as a get var. Sort of the opposite of endpoints I guess.
Not sure if I am explaining this right but have a look at these examples:

```
domain.com/london/contact/,
domain.com/new-york/contact/,
domain.com/contact/
```

All of these would point to the same page "contact" where I could get the city var and customise the output in page.php accordingly. AND I would like to do this for all post_types and pages.

All cities would be posts in a specific post type, so I could load details from there.

Edit:
The rewrite would be about the same as for a language plugin would use I guess.